# Issue with PageBlockSection alignment in lightning experince

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, inputfield, pageblocksection, lightningstylesheets

I have Vf page which is supposed to be used in lightning experience.  I changed the styling using standard attribute lightningStylesheets="true".

But when using PageBlockSection with one column, for classic it is showing the columns as left align, but with lightning experience, the columns flow to the centre of the section. Is there any way we can align them on left while using one column PageBlockSection.

Classic Behaviour(Expected):
[image]

Lightning Experience Behaviour:

[image]

Code Block would be simple pageblock section with one columns:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="primary info" showHeader="false" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField label="Primary Name" value="{!testOb.name}" required="true"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Please share code snippet and actual and expected behavior in screenshots.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Hi Nagendra, Added the snapshots and code for same.

Comment: Using only that, I dont think it will show in center, until you have given a css class to do so, Can you show full code?

Comment: @NagendraSingh No CSS applied for it. In the entire page also, I do not have CSS. It is the default behaviour in lightning Experience. Not sure how to handle it.